# Log in with the MercadoLibre API without having to type user and password?

Tags: php, api, authentication, sdk, vtiger

**Is there any way to login with the MercadoLibre API without having to ask for user and password?**

I need to make a request that is of the form:

```
https://auth.mercadolibre.com.uy?user="someone"&&password="secret"
```

*It's an example, it does not really matter the verb / type of request*

The idea is that the request returns an access token and with it can perform tasks such as answering questions asked by customers to a seller, without the need to log in by manually entering the user and the password of that seller. Since my system must handle several of them.

**Additional data:** It is to integrate an authentication system with vTiger CRM, so I am using the MercadoLibre SDK for the PHP language.

Comment: I'm struggling with this job too!! Have you found the solution yet? Please share it here as an answer to your own question!

Comment: @Heitor No, what I did was read [this article](http://developers.mercadolibre.com/server-side/) to aproach the problem.